# Trying to overlay new AIR 3.8 SDK over the Apache Flex SDK that comes with 3.4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm trying to overlay new AIR 3.8 SDK over the Apache Flex SDK that comes with 3.4

I'm using FB 4.7 and the apache flex sdk download you can get here: https://flex.apache.org/installer.html

So, the thing is even though I downloaded it yesterday It seems to come with Adobe AIR 3.4 but I need to have 3.8

So.... then I went and downloaded the AIR SDK for Mac WITHOUT the new compiler, you'll  see the special Flex link below here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

I then overlayed the Air SDK over the SDK the flex downloader put together for me... I copy+pasted the folder and said "keep newer" that seemed to be the best way to do it I could find online...

So now my issue is that when I set the namespace to 3.8 I get a compile error saying "error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8"

BUT when I set the namespace back to 3.4 now it get an error telling me that I need to set the namespace to 3.8.... but when I do that it says I get the previous error...

So what's going on here? Has anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try creating a new main application file to see what is different in the app descriptor.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing everything correctly. My first instinct was that you may have downloaded the wrong sdk (ie: the one with new compiler) but you've covered that. If you can hold off for a few days, apache flex will shortly be releasing a new installer - with the option to include different AIR SDKs with needing to do a manual overlay.

Comment: Hey Lee, thanks for the tip. If it's really just a few days I think I'll hold out for that update then. Sounds really helpful.

Comment: Hey Reboog, good Idea I'll try that first chance I get.

Comment: Hey @Reboog711 I just did your test, I created a new Flex Mobile project and it is creating it with the 3.8 namespace. But even with an empty test poject when I try and run on an Android device I get this error `error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8` This is pretty strange. I've overlayed a new AIR SDK before, but I'm guessing something about the overlay process could be different with Apache Flex

Comment: @brybam The overlay process should not change with Apache Flex vs Adobe Flex. It sounds like you got the answer; and the problem was that some files were not copied.  Glad to hear you found the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up Terminal (or your command line of choice) and run this:

```
ditto AIR Flex
```

where `AIR` is the path of the newly downloaded AIR SDK and `Flex` is the path of your Flex SDK (you can just drag+drop the folder from Finder into Terminal to get the actual path).

Basically, on Mac when you do a mass copy-paste, it will delete all folders that are being pasted and already exist, rather than merge them (or at least this is what appears happens). So you are actually deleting bits and pieces that you actually need from the Flex SDK. The `ditto` command will preserve these files.

Note: Make sure you backup your Flex SDK (for obvious reasons). If you go to debug Android on-device and cannot, you'll need to grab the Android related launch files from the old SDK to make it work for some devices (such as the Nexus 4). I do not know the location of the files off the top of my head (I run Windows at home, Mac at work), but I could find them out if you need them.

Comment: I thought pasteing the folder in there with the same name then clicking "keep newer" would accomplish this

Comment: well that's what it was. You're right! Coulda sworn that's what "keep newer" did. But thanks!

Comment: Mac file copying is odd. Never really works the way I'd hope it does. There are a few commands you can use to do the overlay, but `ditto` is definitely the easiest to use (not sure if it is the best, however. It works in this case, though)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct,

After trying half a day with copying and pasting and downloading Apache Flex SDK Installer, nothing were right for me. Then I seen this post and did exactly as mentioned.
Finally I got all running now!

for me the terminal command was like this,

```
Nuwans-Mac-Pro:~ nuwan$ ditto /Users/nuwan/Desktop/AdobeAIRSDK /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/4.6.0\ 3.9
```

I did something extra in my case, that I cloned the original SDK and renamed the folder "**4.6.0 3.9**", so in that way I have untouched original SDK in case of screwing things up.

Hope this helps.